# converting signed integer array to char array

Tags: c

I am trying to convert an signed integer array to character pointer. I wrote a sample programe like below. 
Expected output be "10-26357-35"
Please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   int16_t frame_i[5] = {10, -26, 35, 7, -35};
   size_t i;
   char *s = malloc(5*2+1);
   for(i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    snprintf(s + i * 2, 3, "%hd", frame_i[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You reserve 2 `char`s for each number, but the `-` sign in -26 and -35  also ocupies space.

Comment: Actual output? Expected output? Maybe you just have a problem with the sign.

Comment: Expected output "10-26357-35"

Comment: @Abu - Then allocate space for the sign! 2 chars is not enough for `-26`

Comment: you have a 1 digit number too, do you expect this to work with 12345,1,425,8888888, or is it only 1,2 or 3 character numbers (including sign)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take the sign into account. In other words - you can't just assume all numbers to be 2 chars width.

Try something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   int16_t frame_i[5] = {10, -26, 35, 7, -35};
   size_t i;
   char *s = malloc(5*3+1);  // Allocate memory to hold 3 chars for each number

   char *tmp = s;            // Add a tmp pointer to know how far you are

   for(i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    if (frame_i[i] >= 0)     // Check the sign
    {
        snprintf(tmp, 3, "%02hd", frame_i[i]);  // Requires 2 chars
        tmp += 2;
    }
    else
    {
        snprintf(tmp, 4, "%03hd", frame_i[i]);   // Requires 3 chars
        tmp += 3;
    }
   }

   // Print the result
   printf("%s\n", s);

   // Release memory
   free(s);

   return 0;
}
```

Notice that the solution only works for numbers in the range -99 to 99 and that it will put a `0` in front of number in the range -9 to 9.

A more general (and simpler) solution which handles a wider range and doesn't add `0` in front can be obtained by utilizing that `snprintf` returns the number of characters printed. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 1000

int main(void) {
   int16_t frame_i[5] = {10, -26, 35, 7, -35};
   size_t i;
   int size_available = MAX_STRING_SIZE;
   int cnt;
   char *s = malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE);
   char *tmp = s;
   for(i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    cnt = snprintf(tmp, size_available, "%hd", frame_i[i]);
    if (cnt <= 0 || cnt >= size_available)
    {
        printf("Error - snprintf failed or string too short\n");
        free(s);
        return(0);
    }
    size_available -= cnt;
    tmp += cnt;
   }
   printf("%s\n", s);
   free(s);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your solution prints an extra padding `0` in the output: `10-263507-35`. OP asked for `10-26357-35`.

Comment: @skrtbhtngr - Thanks for noticing. Don't know why I assumed that OP actually wanted the zeros. Anyway I posted an alternative solution now.

Comment: For a general solution, better to use the C spec's matching type and specifier :  `int16_t` with `"%"PRTd16` _or_ `short` with  `"%hd"`.

Comment: Minor: `if (cnt <= 0 || ... ` --> `if (cnt < 0 || ... `.  Of course will not make a difference in this case, but a more correct general test of `snprintf()` result - which is _good_ that you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

- When allocating space for the string, give 6 bytes for each array element because you can have at most 6 digits in a signed 16-bit integer (like, -32768) and you are storing digits as a character, not a number.
- You have to adjust the next position for writing according to the digit-length of the number.
- Remember that when you use `snprintf`, the unwritten characters in the string will be `'\0'`, so you would not get a continuous string if you leave gaps in the string while writing to it.
- Also note that the second argument value in `snprintf`, the `n` must be one greater than the maximum width number you want to put (for accommodating `'\0'`.

This would work in **your** case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
       int16_t frame_i[5] = {10, -26, 35, 7, -35};
       size_t i, j;
       char *s = malloc(5*3+1);
       for(i = 0, j=0; i<5; i++) {
           snprintf(s + j, 4, "%hd", frame_i[i]);
           if(frame_i[i]<0 && frame_i[i]<=-10)
                j+=3;
           else if(frame_i[i]<0)
                j+=2;
           else if(frame_i[i] < 10)
                j+=1;
           else
                j+=2;
       }
       printf("%s",s);
       return 0;
}
```